# Is there a name for modules of the form $R/I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ a right ideal of $R$.

> Is there a name for right $R$-modules of the form $R/I$?

When we consider modules such ones arise naturally and are useful when we make (counter) examples. So I suspect there is a name for such important class of modules. I would say those are quotients of the regular module; But I feel there must be simpler one like simple, maximal, cyclic, free, etc.

Comment: I think [cyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_module) cuts it.

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you for comment. It reminds me a module is cyclic iff it is a quotient of the regular module.

Comment: For completeness I cite Corollary 3.9 of 'Rings and Categories of Modules' by Anderson and Fuller.

Comment: Dear @RobArthan : That is a complete answer... could you put it in the solutions section instead of the comments? Thanks...

Comment: I would advise calling these *monogenerated* and boycotting the term "cyclic" altogether. But Rob is correct that they're usually called "cyclic."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such modules are called [cyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_module).